# How to explicitly define an assembly reference for csdl, ssdl & msl files

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-assembly

I have my connection string for my app.config file as follows

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/database.csdl|res://*/database.ssdl|res://*/database.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
```

I am running into the Unable to load the specified metadata resource error.

following this

http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/

I am under the impression of changing the assembly name to something other than /*/ but i dont know how to change it. If someone could tell me where to reference I would appreciate it

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx):

```
Metadata=res://AdventureWorks, 1.0.0.0, neutral, a14f3033def15840/model.csdl|model.ssdl|model.msl
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2exyydhb.aspx) link about how to get fully qualified name of assembly.

Comment: Dennis what i dont get is where you get the 
AdventureWorks, 1.0.0.0, neutral, a14f3033def15840
part from

Comment: @user2094139: this is fully qualified assembly name. I've updated the answer with a link.

Comment: I have the following string

"System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 

Now for my metadata do i have to change it to "System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089/database.csdl ?

Comment: @user2094139: you should point *your* assembly name. The name of assembly, that contains metadata files as linked resources.

Comment: @Dennis hi, I'm having same issue but I can't figure out the fully name of my assembly.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231089/metadataexception-schema-specified-is-not-valid